# Book with illegal futuristic car racing, interplanetary travel

Tags: story-identification, books

I read only a part of this book maybe 6 years ago, and I've been searching for it since.

All I remember is:

Futuristic setting, female protagonist, possibly a teenager, participating in illegal races, gets caught, but is offered the chance to race professionally. At this point I believe she is flown off planet in a rocket. She practices in the official cars on a track, but if I recall, can't seem do very well.

I recall the cover art being a red(?) car on a black background. This was a hardback book. I don't recall specifically if they were combustion, but I believe so. And I believe that they might have been specialized racing cars, but not to the degree of Formula 1. I'd say it's closer to Fast and Furious with the customized cars.

That's all I really recall, hopefully it's enough. I think the characters name was "Mia" but that might be totally wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to recall the cover art at all?  Was this an e-book, a paperback or a hardcover?

Comment: You say the setting is futuristic; are they still driving internal combustion engine vehicles?  Are they specialized racing cars (like Formula 1), or is it more like *Fast & Furious* with illegal street racing of modified consumer vehicles?

Comment: @DavidW I recall the cover art being a red(?) car on a black background. This was a hardback book. I don't recall specifically if they were combustion, but I believe so. And I believe so, yes, they might have been specialized racing cars, but not to the degree of formula 1. I'd say it's closer to Fast and Furious with the customized cars.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possibly [Tracked](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23281932-tracked) by Jenny Martin?

> This story takes place on another planet called Castra. In the slums, we follow Phoebe, who street races like a boss with her best friend, Bear. She's the daughter of an old circuit-racing legend. After being arrested for street racing and she is faced with a lifetime of labour camps, Phoebe is offered an opportunity to race for one of the biggest corporations in the world, Benroyal. Struggling with the fact she feels like she's selling out is the least of her worries and she falls headfirst into the corrupted and glamorous life that these corporate suits control.

The cover doesn't match your memory, though the Polish edition does have a red car on the cover:

[image: Tracked]

It was published in 2015 so that matches your memory of reading it six years ago.

Comment: I THINK THAT'S IT!!!! HOLY MOLY YOU'RE MAGICAL